# Various connection via telnet with/without password

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

```
import telnetlib
import os
import re

current_dir = os.getcwd()
IP = <IP>

def login_as_root():

    print "logging in as root..."
    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write("root\r")
    response = tn.expect([re.compile(b"Password:"),b"root@",])
    if "Password:" in response[2]:
        send_msg("root", "root@")
    else:
        print "logging without passwd"

def send_msg(msg, wait_str, print_msg=0):
    if print_msg:
        print msg
    tn.write("%s\n" % msg)
    return tn.read_until(wait_str)

def launch_update():
    try:
        print send_msg("mount -o remount,rw /", "root@ ", print_msg=1)
    except:
        Exception("Update configuring is failed")

def main():
    global tn
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
        login_as_root()
    except:
        raise Exception("Connect failed")

    launch_update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Need help with login_as_root(). There are 2 cases to login as root: with password and without any password. I have to connect correctly to host and then launch several commands in launch_update(). Script stucks after mount command.

Comment: `"root@ "` should that final space be there?

Comment: Removing spaces is helped. I don't really understand why because I've changed only login_as_root() and before that script works ok. Thank you!

Comment: `launch_update` expects that the session prompt will start with "root@ ". If that used to work, then it could be that the old `login_as_root` set the `PS1` environment variable which controls what the prompt looks like. That's all just a guess!